# gnuplot output filename from csv file

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I have a CSV file and I am plotting the columns one by one in a do for[] loop. I would like to save the plot as a PNG file, with the filename coming from the columnheader. What is the best way to go about this where text.png is replaced by the ith column header?

```
#!/bin/bash
set datafile separator ","
set key autotitle columnhead
set xlabel "time/date"
nc = "`awk -F, 'NR == 1{ print NF; exit}' input.csv`"
set term png

do for [i = 2:5] {
set output "test.png"
plot 'HiveLongrun.csv' every::0 using i:xticlabels(1) with lines
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using awk, you could use it once more to get the header name from inside a gnuplot macro:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set datafile separator ","
set key autotitle columnhead
set xlabel "time/date"
nc = "`awk -F, 'NR == 1{ print NF; exit}' input.csv`"

# Define a macro which, when evaluated, assigns the ith column header
# to the variable 'head'
awkhead(i) = "head = \"\`awk -F, 'NR == 1 {print $".i."}' input.csv\`\""

set term png

do for [i = 2:5] {
    eval awkhead(i)          # evaluate the macro
    set output head.".png"   # use the 'head' variable assigned by the macro
    plot 'HiveLongrun.csv' every::0 using i:xticlabels(1) with lines
}
```

There is almost certainly a cleaner way to do this with another awk-like utility, or even within gnuplot.  Gnuplot offers a few ways to run arbitrary internal/external commands, as you can see from my mix of backtics and macro evaluation.

By the way, it is a little strange to me that you have the bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) at the start of the script if it will presumably be interpreted by gnuplot.  I assume you call it as `gnuplot myscript.plt`.  In this case the shebang is just a comment (as far as gnuplot is concerned) and doesn't do anything because gnuplot is the interpreter.  In my example I use `#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot` and I run the script as an executable in bash, like `./myscript.plt`.  The shebang in this case tells bash to make gnuplot the interpreter (or whatever command you would get by typing `gnuplot` at the command prompt).  Of course you could also set the shebang to be `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot` if you're not worried about the path changing.

Comment: print $".i." was what was giving me problems, I was trying print $i